# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification android google places

Tags: android, listview, exception, android-arrayadapter, google-places-api

I am using google places autocomplete and I am getting the following error:
**(does not happen always only some times)**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(-1, class android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with Adapter(class locationplacesautocomplete.GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter)]

 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1582)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2627)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16821)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16821)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
```

After reading the following message I used runOnUiThread() for notifyDataSetChanged() but still not working.

I will add the adapter class:

```
package locationplacesautocomplete;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import datatypes.AutoCompleteData;

/**
 * This class implements the adapter for google places auto complete
 * Created by edenbensimon on 07/06/15.
 */
public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

    // Holds an array list with the results
    private Object[] resultList;
    private HashMap<String, String> result;
    private Activity _activity;

    // Default ctor
    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Activity activity) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        _activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList[index].toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    result = AutoCompleteLogic.autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                    resultList = result.keySet().toArray();

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.length;
                }
                return filterResults;
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, final FilterResults results) {
                _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array list with only description about the place
     */
    private ArrayList getDescOnly(ArrayList values) {
        ArrayList returnValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            returnValue.add(((AutoCompleteData)values.get(i)).getDescription());
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(HashMap<String, String> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Object[] getResultList() {
        return resultList;
    }

    public void setResultList(Object[] resultList) {
        this.resultList = resultList;
    }
}
```

And this is my compute logic

```
/**
 * This method gets the current input and returns list with all suitable cities
 * @return
 */
public static HashMap autocomplete(String input) {

    // Initialize the variable
    HashMap<String, String> result = null;

    // The url connection will be used
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    // String builder for the json results
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Build the string for the url
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);

        // This parameter is used for choosing specific country, not must.
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));


  // Create the url
    URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    // Load the results into a StringBuilder
    int read;
    char[] buff = new char[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
        jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
    return result;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
    return result;
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}

try {
    // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

    // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
    result = new HashMap<>(predsJsonArray.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        result.put(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"),
                   predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
}

return result;
```

}

Does anyone has an idea whats wrong? what to take card of?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Eden

Comment: Do some debugging; when does it happen? This `if (results != null && results.count > 0)` might be the culprit.

Comment: I am currently trying to debug but the problem is that it occurs once in many times.. so hard to catch it. Thanks for the point with the if, Ill check it out now again

Comment: @mvai so far it does not seem related

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in adaptor after every data change/set.

Comment: can you please explain where and why?

Comment: Because you are updating data using setter methods, but the widget will not know about this update. So widget and adaptor are not in sync. `notifyDataSetChanged ` will notify widget to sync with adaptor.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. you mean to set it after perform filtering?

Comment: now also:
  An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: you meant to this right: in performFiltering
// Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.length;
                    if (filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }